# Performance issue using new paging stynax in SQL Server 2012 (OFFSET n ROWS FETCH NEXT m ROWS ONLY)

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-execution-plan

I found a [post](http://www.kodyaz.com/sql-server-2012/sql-paging-in-sql-server-2012-sql-order-by-offset-fetch-next-rows.aspx) about new paging stynax in SQL Server 2012. Like

```
SELECT p.ProductName
FROM Products p
ORDER BY p.ProductID

OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

That was great. But when I look into Execution Plan, the cost is 100%. Does it mean the SELECT statement will fetch all rows and then do the paing? which will cause a performance issue?

I am new to SQL Server, can anyone tell me about this? thanks.

[image: Screen shot of Execution Plan]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No cost means what is the cost of a particular statement compared to all the statements. Since you have  only one statement, it is taking 100% of the whole execution time. If you had two statements, then it would have split the cost.

Also to avoid confusion, I suggest you write the query this way which makes it clear that the OFFSET is actually part of the SELECT query:

```
SELECT p.ProductName
FROM Products p
ORDER BY p.ProductID
   OFFSET 10 ROWS
   FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Helps?